# TF_API_TOKEN secret not shared with shared GitHub Action

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I had a GitHub Action that had got quite long and had a lot of repeated code. So I decomposed it to use shared actions via `workflow_call`. Prior to doing this, I could authenticate with the `terraform` CLI by the fact that I had a secret defined in the GitHub repository called `TF_API_TOKEN` that contained my Terraform Cloud API key.

Now when I run the shared workflow the code errors:

```
terraform -chdir=deploy/environments/dev/bucket init


Initializing Terraform Cloud...
Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: Error accessing remote module registry
│ 
│   on main.tf line 25:
│   25: module "app_bucket" {
│ 
│ Failed to retrieve available versions for module "app_bucket" (main.tf:25)
│ from app.terraform.io: error looking up module versions: 401 Unauthorized.
```

I believe this is due to the secret not being accessible from the shared action. How can I get around this?

**Code**

*branch-feature.yml*

```yaml
name: Deploy Feature Branch

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build:
    if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'feature/') || github.head_ref == 'master'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-build.yml

  deploy-to-dev:
    needs: [build]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-deploy.yml
    with:
      deploy-env: dev
      deploy-branch: ${{ github.head_ref }}
```

*step-deploy.yml*

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      deploy-env:
        required: true
        description: 'Environment to deploy to'
        type: string
      deploy-branch:
        required: true
        description: 'Branch to deploy'
        type: string
  
jobs:
  get-version:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-version.yml

  deploy-infrastructure:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-deploy-infrastructure.yml
    with:
      deploy-env: ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
      deploy-branch: ${{ inputs.deploy-branch }}
      script-directory: bucket
```

*step-deploy-infrastructure.yml*

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      deploy-env:
        required: true
        description: 'Environment to deploy to'
        type: string
      deploy-branch:
        required: true
        description: 'Branch to deploy'
        type: string
      script-directory:
        required: true
        description: 'Directory to run terraform from'
        type: string
      terraform-args:
        required: false
        description: 'Additional arguments to pass to terraform'
        type: string
        default: ""
    outputs:
      bucket-name:
        description: 'The name of the s3 bucket created'
        value: ${{ jobs.deploy.outputs.bucket-name }}
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
    outputs:
      bucket-name: ${{ steps.bucket_name.outputs.stdout }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ inputs.deploy-branch }}
      - name: Configure Environment based on branches
        run: |
          echo "TF-DIRECTORY=deploy/environments/${{ inputs.deploy-env }}/${{ inputs.script-directory }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Setup terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}
      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} fmt -check
      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} init
      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} validate -no-color
      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} plan -no-color
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Update Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
        env:
          PLAN: "terraform\n${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const output = `#### Terraform Format and Style \`${{ steps.fmt.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Initialization ⚙️\`${{ steps.init.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Plan \`${{ steps.plan.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Validation \`${{ steps.validate.outputs.stdout }}\`
  
            <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>
  
            \`\`\`\n
            ${process.env.PLAN}
            \`\`\`
  
            </details>
  
            *Pusher: @${{ github.actor }}, Action: \`${{ github.event_name }}\`*`;
  
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })
      - name: Terraform Plan Status
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
        run: exit 1
      - name: Terraform Apply ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} apply -auto-approve ${{ inputs.terraform-args }}
      - name: Get Bucket Name
        id: bucket_name
        run: terraform -chdir=${{ env.TF-DIRECTORY }} output -raw bucket_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow), you need to **inherit secrets** when calling a reusable worklow.

So instead of using:

```
  deploy-infrastructure:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-deploy-infrastructure.yml
    with:
      deploy-env: ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
      deploy-branch: ${{ inputs.deploy-branch }}
      script-directory: bucket
```

You should inform the secret when calling the reusable workflow:

```
  deploy-infrastructure:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-deploy-infrastructure.yml
    with:
      deploy-env: ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
      deploy-branch: ${{ inputs.deploy-branch }}
      script-directory: bucket
    secrets:
      TF_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}
```

To enable this, you need to add the secret to the `workflow_call` configuration in the `step-deploy-infrastruture.yaml` file:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
       [ ... ]
    secrets:
      TF_API_TOKEN:
        required: true
```

Also note that:

> Workflows that call reusable workflows in the same organization or enterprise can use the inherit keyword to implicitly pass the secrets.

In that case, you could use:

```
  deploy-infrastructure:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/step-deploy-infrastructure.yml
    with:
      deploy-env: ${{ inputs.deploy-env }}
      deploy-branch: ${{ inputs.deploy-branch }}
      script-directory: bucket
    secrets: inherit
```

Comment: The first way I could not get to work. However, `secrets: inherit` did the trick.